# Create menu item for a specific excel file

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want a specific menu / button to appear in the ribbon, whenever user open a particular file.  Is that possible ?

To make it clear, wheneven user opens "ABC.xlsx", I want a menu / button to appear in the ribbon on the top, which should be visible until the user closes the file.

I saw option to create custom right click menu.  I'm looking for option in standard menu.

Comment: Please check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @Maddy... Unfortunately that is not working for excel.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim MenuBar As CommandBar
    Dim NewMenu As CommandBarPopup
    Dim NewSubMenu As CommandBarPopup
    Dim NewMenuItem As CommandBarButton
    ' Create new item on Worksheet Menu Bar
    Set MenuBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
    Set NewMenu = MenuBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    NewMenu.Caption = "new menu"

    Set NewMenuItem = NewMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With NewMenuItem
    .Caption = "My Menu" ' Menu name
    .FaceId = 9
    .OnAction = "Module1.Mymacro" ' call macro here
    End With

    End Sub
```